Pooling time series data in R
I think this might be a common problem but I could not find an answer for this.
I have yearly data and I would like to create a pooled group (i.e., a new year that combines the data from the previous year). For the combined years, I would like to pick the non-missing value from year 3. If year 3 is missing I would like to pick the maximum of the values in prior years.
here is the what the input looks like:
        df <- tibble(
        ID=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3),
        Year = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
        column1 = c(10,11,NA,12,11,NA,14,NA, 15),
        column2 = c(8,NA,15,NA,NA,NA,NA, 14,16)
      )

And the output:
  df <- tibble(
    ID=c(1,2,3),
    Year = c("combined", "combined", "combined"),
    column1 = c(11, 12, 15),
    column2 = c(15, NA, 16)
  )  

Many thanks for your help in advance.

An approach using sort within across
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(Year = "combined", 
            across(starts_with("col"), ~ 
              if_else(is.na(.x[3]), sort(.x, decreasing=T)[1], .x[3])), 
            .by = ID)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID Year     column1 column2
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 combined      11      15
2     2 combined      12      NA
3     3 combined      15      16

Note, using sort since
max(c(NA,NA), na.rm=T)
[1] -Inf
Warning message:
In max(c(NA, NA), na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf


thank you so much, this is simple and elegant.
